# How to downcast in C++ to call a child function from a parent instance?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to call a child function from a parent instance using explicit down-casting (thanks for pointing out @Aconcagua). As a beginner in C++, I have something like this:

```
Road currentRoad = ...;
duration = ((SpeedDataRoad) currentRoad).getSpeedProfileTime(dateinMillis, isRightDirection);
```

class `SpeedDataRoad` inherits from `Road`:

```
class SpeedDataRoad : public Road{ 
     double getSpeedProfileTime(long dateinMillis, bool isRightDirection) {

     ...

}
```

However I am getting the error:

> No matching conversion for C-style cast from 'Road' to 'SpeedDataRoad'

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

---

Just to be clear, what I am trying to achieve in Java would be written like this and working correctly:

```
duration = ((SpeedDataRoad) currentRoad).getSpeedProfileTime(currentTime, isRightDirection);
```

Comment: That's down-, not up-casting...

Comment: @Rrz0 A base class knows nothing about its derived classes. So you can not make such a conversion.

Comment: When learning C++, forget **everything** you learned about Java. It is only going to cause you woe and misery. To begin with, in C++ you have to use *pointers* or *references* to use polymorphism. An object is an object, it always has static typing. Pointers can be resolved dynamically.

Comment: If you end up in this situation, you need to redesign.

Comment: Just move `getSpeedProfileTime()` function into `Road` interface. It might be a virtual function, if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) your `SpeedDataRoad` object.  Unlike Java objects, which have pointer/reference semantics, C++ objects have value semantics.  That means, in your example, `currentRoad` is a `Road`, not a `SpeedDataRoad`.  It is a *copy* of the `Road` part of whatever `SppedDataRoad` is created in your `...`.

To work with polymorphism is C++ you need to use references or pointers.  That is, the following will **not** work because `currentRoad` **is not** a `SpeedDataRoad`:

```
double foo(Road currentRoad)
{
    //...
    return ((SpeedDataRoad)currentRoad).getSpeedProfileTime(currentTime, isRightDirection);
}

int main()
{
    SpeedDataRoad road;
    foo(road);
}
```

While the following **will** work because `currentRoad` **references** a `SpeedDataRoad`:

```
double foo(Road& currentRoad)
//             ^---------------- Pass by reference now
{
    //...
    return dynamic_cast<SpeedDataRoad&>(currentRoad).getSpeedProfileTime(currentTime, isRightDirection);
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    //     Using C++-style cast and casting reference to reference
}

int main()
{
    SpeedDataRoad road;
    foo(road);
}
```

In the first example, `currentRoad` is a *copy* of the `Road` part of `road`, while in the second example `currentRoad` is a *reference* to `road`.

---

You should also avoid C-style casts in C++.  In this instance, it would be better to use `dynamic_cast<SpeedDataRoad&>(currentRoad)` or, if you're absolutely sure `currentRoad` will always be a reference to a `SpeedDataRoad` object, `static_cast<SpeedDataRoad&>(currentRoad)`.  The former will do runtime type checking and throw an exception if `currentRoad` isn't a reference to a `SpeedDataRoad` while the latter will avoid the (small) overhead of doing runtime type checking, but will result in undefined behavior if `currentRoad` isn't a reference to a `SpeedDataRoad`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. When I try the second example I get `Road is not polymorphic`. I read elsewhere that "you cannot dynamic_cast a non-polymorphic type. static_cast is the cast you would use in this case..."

Comment: @Rrz0 Sounds suspicious. Why a pointer/reference to non-polymorphic base and then casting down again? As long as you use the derived classes as in example here, fine, yet, as soon as you try to `delete` a derived object via pointer to base you are in big trouble without a virtual destructor.

Comment: You have to explicitly mark member functions `virtual` for a type to be polymorphic in C++ (unlike Java, where all methods are implicitly `virtual`).

Answer (score 6):

You suffer from an effect called *'object slicing'*:

```
SpeedDataRoad sdr;
Road currentRoad = sdr;
```

At the second line, `sdr` is assigned *by value* to `currentRoad`, but the latter is not of appropriate type to hold a complete `SpeedDataRoad` object. So all surplus pieces of `SpeedDataRoad` are simply cut away and all that remains is a pure `Road` object only containing the `Road` parts of original `sdr` object.

At the same time, as you only have a pure `Road` object left, you cannot cast it back to `SpeedDataRoad` object. Where should the now missing parts come from?

This is exactly the same reason why you cannot place polymorphic types directly into a container (like `std::vector`) of the base class.

What you need are either pointers (if you want to be able to re-assign) or references (to be preferred otherwise):

```
SpeedDataRoad sdr;
Road& currentRoad = sdr;
//  ^ (!)
// or:
Road* currentRoad = &sdr;
```

*Now* you can do the cast. But explicit down-casts have a smell of bad design. You might be better off with a polymorphic approach right from the start:

```
class Road
{
public:
    virtual double getSpeedProfileTime(long, bool) = 0;
    //                                             ^ pure virtual
    // alternatively, you can provide a default implementation
};

class SpeedDataRoad : public Road
{
public:
    double getSpeedProfileTime(long, bool) override
    { /* ... */ }
};
```

Now you can simply have:

```
SpeedDataRoad sdr;
Road& currentRoad = sdr;
double profile = currentRoad.getSpeedProfileTime(0, false);
```

As being virtual, you'll always get the right variant of the function, no matter which sub-class we have at all and in which way it might override the function...

**Side note 1:** Instead of old C-style casts, you might prefer the more modern C++ casts, you can control more fine grained what you actually want to do:

```
Road* someRoad = ...;
SpeedDataRoad* sdr = static_cast<SpeedDataRoad*>(someRoad);
SpeedDataRoad* sdr = dynamic_cast<SpeedDataRoad*>(someRoad);
```

You would use a `static_cast`, if you are 100% sure that the object *only* can be of desired type. You avoid any run-time tests that wouldn't serve anything at all in this situation (you are 100% sure anyway, remember?). [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is a typical scenario for.

If you cannot be sure about the type, then `dynamic_cast` comes into play, it will do some run-time type checking and just return a null pointer (if used on pointers) or throw a `std::bad_cast` (if used on references), if the actual type is not of desired type (or a sub class of). Such a scenario can arise when different polymorphic types are stored in a vector (as pointers to base class, see above). But again: Needing a cast at all might be a hint to your design being flawed...

(For completeness: There are yet `const_cast` and `reinterpret_cast`, but you should stay away from these unless/until you *really, really* know what you do.)

**Side note 2:** Differences to Java.

In Java, we differentiate implicitly between native and reference types. Native ones are always passed by value, reference types always by reference – well, *Java reference*, which actually resembles far more a C++ *pointer* (can be `null`, can be re-assigned) than a C++ reference. In Java, this happens *implicitly*, in C++, you need to be explicit about (on the other hand, you can have both behaviours for *any* type).

Java cast on (Java!) reference behaves like C++ `dynamic_cast` (on reference, i. e. throws, it won't return `null` on type mismatch).

Finally (concerning my polymorphism recommendation), in Java all functions are *implicitly* virtual, in C++, you again have to be explicit about (apply the `virtual` keyword, see above).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That's called a downcast and not an upcast - the straightforward way to this by a `dynamic_cast`:

```
if (SpeedDataRoad* sdroad = dynamic_cast<SpeedDataRoad*>(&currentRoad); sdroad != nullptr) {
   duration = sdroad->getSpeedProfileTime(currentTime, isRightDirection);
}
```

Comment: You could equivalently have written: `if(false)`: The cast will fail on `Road currentRoad` in any case...

Comment: @Aconcagua yeah yea, well I wrote the answer such that the OP might discover on his own the possible slicing etc.

Comment: Hm. You might have at least left some hints, otherwise this answer just will provoke a new question '*Why do I get a null pointer?'* here on SO...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check inside a function if you can downcast a pointer/refernce into a child, you need to use dynamic cast.

```cpp
void foo(Road* road){
  SpeedDataRoad* child{nullptr};
  if(child = dynamic_cast<SpeedDaraRoad*>(road){
    // Do something with SpeedDataRoad
  } else {
     // road is not an instance of SpeedDataRoad
  }
}
```

You can also use `dynamic_cast` with references, like so

```
cppSpeedDataRoad& child = dynamic_cast<SpeedDataRoad&>(reference_to_road);
```

But be carefull, as if the cast fails, `std::bad_cast` will be throw.

Comment: `SpeedDataRoad* child = dynamic_cast<SpeedDaraRoad*>(road); if(child)` would have been much nicer – or even C++17 variant `if(SpeedDataRoad* child = dynamic_cast<SpeedDaraRoad*>(road); child)`...

Answer (score 0):

In C++, we try not to use C-style casting. `(typename)object`.
Instead, there are 4 types of type-casting.

1. `static_cast<typename*>(pointer) static_cast<typename>(value)`: Upcasting of pointers and type-casting for value types
2. `dynamic_cast<typename*>(pointer)`: Safe-downcasting of pointers (the one you should use). It does a runtime check for upcasting, hence, there is runtime cost.
3. `const_cast<...>(...)`: Constant type
4. `reinterpret_cast<typename*>(pointer) reinterpret_cast<typename>(value)`: Similar to C-style cast.

For objects (stack allocated), I rarely use casting. Because naturally objects in C++ has their own size, casting may change their size.

Comment: Technically correct, but not an answer to actual question. The cast fails for a totally different reason, and none of the C++ casts could be applied either...

Comment: Ya, one important thing is upcasting is only for pointer-casting since size of the object changes

Comment: *Down*-casting. Well, you *could* use for up-casts as well, but those are implicit anyway...

Comment: @Aconcagua Totally agree. Anw, if we know wth we are doing, C-style casting can be used everywhere.